# Violation class bravo airspace

Tags: faa-regulations

I was flying under class bravo airspace at 1800 feet which was the legal altitude 1800 and below but my transponder is off by 200 feet so they thought I was 2000. when I landed and i had to talk to the tower. He did not say anything except be careful and turn your altimeter down next time and be careful. nothing else happened but am I OK? did the get my n number ? i never gave them my name or info.

Comment: Sounds like you just got a verbal warning because it was an honest mistake.  Don't worry.  I doubt the FBI is going to raid your house.  The tower folks probably had more important things to do than file violation paperwork for a 200 ft altimeter error.

Comment: Disagree that this is a dupe.  He didn't fly into B.  He is asking how to deal with a call from ATC  telling him to be careful.  He's done nothing wrong.  A question about dealing with the fallout from doing something wrong will have a different answer than a question about an ATC mistake.

Comment: @acpilot I agree, not a duplicate. I think I voted to close this question as unclear. If Bob can clarify exactly what his question is, it might be worth re-opening. Given our current information, we probably don't know enough to answer his two questions properly ("am I OK?" and "did they get my N number?").

Answer (score 3):

You're probably fine.  File a ASRS form all the same though.

The feds tend to focus on safety of flight issues or gross violations that indicate general incompetence.  Some guy flying below a B shelf doesn't rise to the level of incompetence (because it's not).  Worst case, you caused a resolution advisory for an airliner which, in the grand scheme, is not a huge deal (for you, legally) if you were following the rules (sounds like you were).

If you get a letter, call an aviation attorney.  I doubt it will come to that though.

Keep on flying.

Comment: Not clear there was even a violation, but I absolutely agree with the NASA ASRS report filing.